# How to simulate a batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, simulate

I need to setup a PowerShell script based upon a batch script.  The original batch script looks like the following:

```
call %SYSTEMROOT%\setup_Env.BAT
command_name command_arguments
```

The command is dependent upon the environmental variables from the `setup_ENV.BAT` being setup.

```
$tempFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$script = "%SYSTEMROOT%\setup_Env.BAT"
cmd /c " $script && set > $tempFile "
cmd /c " command_name command_arguments"
```

I received the error:

> cmd : 'command_name is not recognized as an internal or external command,...

If there is a better way to do this in PowerShell, I am open to it.

Comment: Just trying for a direct replacement of commands from BAT to PS1 is probably not the best approach.  What is the end goal of your scripting?

Comment: I know it seems like a pain but in the long run you would probably be better off re-writing the bat file in powershell.

Comment: Assuming that `setup_env.bat` is defining some environment variables required for `command_name` you cannot simply run the batch script from PowerShell to the same end. When run from CMD the called batch script modifies the CMD process' environment. However, when invoked from PowerShell the batch script will run in a CMD child process and modify that process' environment. When the child process terminates the modifications are lost. The environment of the PowerShell process remains unchanged. Thus re-writing the script in PowerShell may actually be required.

Comment: For further help please show the content of `setup_env.bat`.

Comment: If your original batch script runs without errors but you receive that error only when running through PowerShell script then the problem resides in the way you invoke command_name in Poweshell. Then this should resolve the problem: `cmd /c "$script && set > $tempFile & command_name command_arguments"`

Comment: Ansgar, unfortunately, the setup_env.bat is a vendor software generated script which I do not want to modify nor convert to Powershell.  Any software update will mostly like change in the future.just overwrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **pass a *single* command line to `cmd`** to make this work:

```
cmd /c "call %SYSTEMROOT%\setup_Env.BAT && command_name command_arguments"
```

As [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) points out, every `cmd` invocation runs in a child process, and any environment modifications made in a child process are not visible to the calling process and therefore also not to future child processes.

By contrast, in the single command line above, the environment-variable modifications performed by `setup_Env.BAT` *are* visible to `command_name` by the time it executes.

---

**Caveat**: **If `command_arguments` contains `%...%`-style references** to the environment **variables defined in `setup_Env.BAT`**, more work is needed:

- Change the `%...%`-style references to `!...!`-style references.
- Additionally invoke `cmd` with `/v` to enable delayed variable expansion (the equivalent of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` inside a script`:

  ```
  cmd /v /c "call %SYSTEMROOT%\setup_Env.BAT && command_name args_with_delayed_var_refs"
  ```

---

**Caveat**: The above **may still not work as intended if `command_arguments` happens to contain `!` chars. that should be treated as *literals*** (and/or `command_name` is another batch file containing such).

In that event, the simplest approach is to simply **recreate the entire batch file in a temporary file and invoke that**:

```
# Get temp. file path
$tempBatFile = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.bat'

# Write the content of the temp. batch file
@'
@echo off
call %SYSTEMROOT%\setup_Env.BAT
command_name command_arguments
'@ | Set-Content $tempBatFile

# Execute it.
& $tempBatFile 

# Clean up.
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $tempBatFile
```

Comment: Congrats to the 6th digit. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @AnsgarWiechers - happy to join the club you’ve been a member of for quite some time.